# ElasticSearch - Filtering a result and manipulating the documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following query - which works fine (this might not be the actual query):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "location",
            "query": {
              "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "16090km",
                "distance_type": "arc",
                "location.point": {
                  "lat": "51.794177",
                  "lon": "-0.063055"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "16090km",
            "distance_type": "arc",
            "location.point": {
              "lat": "51.794177",
              "lon": "-0.063055"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Although I want to do the following (as part of the query but not affecting the existing query):

- Find all documents that have `field_name` = `1`
- On all documents that have `field_name` = `1` run ordering by geo_distance
- Remove duplicates that have `field_name` = `1` and the same value under `field_name_2` = `2` and leave the closest item in the documents result, but remove the rest

Update (further explanation):

Aggregations can't be used as we want to manipulate the documents in the result.

Whilst also maintaining the order within the documents; meaning:

If I have 20 documents, sorted by a field; and I have 5 of which have field_name = 1, I would like to sort the 5 by distance, and eliminate 4 of them; whilst still maintaining the first sort. (possibly doing the geodistance sort and elimination before the actual query?)

Not too sure how to do this, any help is appreciated - I'm currently using ElasticSearch DSL DRF - but I can easily convert the query to ElasticSearch DSL.

Example documents (before manipulation):

```
[{
"field_name": 1,
"field_name_2": 2,
"location": ....
},
{
"field_name": 1,
"field_name_2": 2,
"location": ....
},
{
"field_name": 55,
"field_name_5": 22,
"location": ....
}]
```

Output (Desired):

```
[{
"field_name": 1,
"field_name_2": 2,
"location": .... <- closest
},
{
"field_name": 55,
"field_name_5": 22,
"location": ....
}]
```

Comment: So your query above returns all documents within a given distance of a given point, but they are not ordered by distance... However, I'm not sure how your other condition `field_name = 1` should combine with that initial query. Can you explain in more details what you mean by `as part of the query but not affecting the existing query`?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly - so the query I have at the moment sorts and filters by distance (as shown in the query above) - although I also want to have a separate part (because not all queries sort by distance) to sort all documents that have field_name = 1, and just pick the first document (being the closest) - i.e finding the closest document with field_name = 1, and removing the rest, but also leaving the ones that don't have field_name = 1, as is.

Comment: Ok, because I didn't see any sort clause in your query, so you're just relying on the default `_score` sort, right?

Comment: Yes @Val, we're just relying on the default sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `Field Collapsing` - which is the equivalent of grouping. - Below is an example of how this can be achieved:

```
{"collapse": {"field": "vin",
              "inner_hits": {
                  "name": "closest_dealer",
                  "size": 1,
                  "sort": [
                      {
                          "_geo_distance": {
                              "location.point": {
                                  "lat": "latitude",
                                  "lon": "longitude"
                              },
                              "order": "desc",
                              "unit": "km",
                              "distance_type": "arc",
                              "nested_path": "location"
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
              }
 }
```

The collapsing is done on the field `vin` - and the `inner_hits` is used to sort the grouped items and get the closest one. (size = 1)

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what you want is to keep the query part as you have it now (so you still get the hits you need) and add an aggregation part in order to get the closest document with an additional condition on `filed_name`. The aggregation part would be made of:

- a [`filter` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to only consider the documents with `field_name = 1`
- a [`geo_distance` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geodistance-aggregation.html) with a very small distance
- a [`top_hits` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to return the document with the closest distance

The aggregation part would look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    ...same as you have now...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "field_name": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "field_name": 1           <--- only select desired documents
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "field": "location.point",
          "unit": "km",
          "distance_type": "arc",
          "origin": {
            "lat": "51.794177",
            "lon": "-0.063055"
          },
          "ranges": [
            {
              "to": 1               <---- single bucket for docs < 1km (change as needed)
            }
          ]
        },
        "aggs": {
          "closest": {
            "top_hits": {
              "size": 1,            <---- closest document
              "sort": [
                {
                  "_geo_distance": {
                    "location.point": {
                      "lat": "51.794177",
                      "lon": "-0.063055"
                    },
                    "order": "asc",
                    "unit": "km",
                    "mode": "min",
                    "distance_type": "arc",
                    "ignore_unmapped": true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks @Val, may I ask what does the `ranges` do exactly? (single bucket)

Comment: The `geo_distance` aggregation allows to create buckets of documents sitting between a from-to distance of a given point (sort of like concentric circles). Here we're just interested in the smallest bucket at the center of the circle. You can adjust the `to` value as you see fit to make as small as possible

Comment: Ah cool! thank you for the explanation! :) If I have the geo_distance filter in the `query` do I need to do it again over here? - would it be enough to sort by distance?

Comment: will the result be outside of the normal query result? is there another way of doing this if so?

Comment: Yes, the result will be in the aggregations section. Can you try the query and see how it works?

Comment: I need to convert it into ElasticSearch DSL first, but if it's separate I'm still going to need to change it :x

Comment: Ok, let me know

Comment: Another solution could also be to do 2 queries (using the [`_msearch` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html))

Comment: Tried it using a client, it works well! but the results are out of the search result (under aggs) - I need the results to stay in their position in the result set :/ but remove the `field_name` = `1` that isn't the closest :s

Comment: How would that look @Val? sorry but I'm not very aware of how ElasticSearch works

Comment: It's important that if I have 10 documents and 2 of them are `field_name` = 1 and are in the 5th place - after sorting them by geolocation and removing the 1 that is not closest, that it stays in the 5th place :/ it's overly complicated, it seems anyway.

Comment: The logic per se that I'm looking for is: 1. run a sort on documents that have field_name = 1 (after all the sorting that might have happened before on the documents), 2. leave the first document, whilst maintaining the order of the other records that are not field_name = 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225394/discussion-between-julian-camilleri-and-val).